# Is it possible to detect Firefox users in pure CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, browser-detection

Is it possible to detect Firefox Browser only with CSS like IE?

for example, IE browser can be detected like:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
   /* IMPORTING CSS FOR IE */
<![endif]-->
```

Can be Firefox browser detected like this code?

Comment: Basically, no. So far as conditional comments go it's either IE or not-IE, unfortunately.

Comment: Please use a descriptive title when posting a question instead of just a seperated set of keywords.

Comment: The question is why you would want to detect Firefox? Do you have any certain reason to do so? Firefox CSS support isn't broken, unlike IE.

Comment: I want to change some element position only for Firefox.  in other browsers it works correctly.

Comment: @GlitchMr Are you serious? You think Firefox doesn't display things differently (like all individual browsers)? What do you mean why would he want to do this? I just got through making a complex form for a database-driven web-interface site, and Firefox is the only browser that for some reason likes to scrunch all the texareas too close to the other fields. If I spread them out then they are too far apart for IE and Chrome. I know that detecting a browser and styling differently based on this detection shouldn't be the first answer, but to wonder why he would want this is just, well, weird...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you can try this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 
    #my-id { font-size: 100%; }
 
}
```

[This website](http://web.archive.org/web/20110305101802/http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/) has more options as well

You can place this in your CSS file or between your `<style type='text/css'>` tags in your HTML. Works Fine!

Comment: @Peppered Lemons Do you mind clarifying where that goes? CSS file, js file, or cshtml file?

Comment: awesome! Does anyone know whey the url-prefix() needs to be included?

Answer (score 33):

## Nowadays you can use the [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) CSS rule:

```
@supports not( -moz-appearance:none ){
  /* Add non-firefox CSS code here */
}
```

Comment: Really helpful. But to get it to work in Chrome, I had to add a space between 'not' and '('

Comment: It fits into scss also