# Is it possible to retain some part of the content from input placeholder?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Input box in the card below accepts value in percentage. Hence, I have got a placeholder in the input box that says Percentage (%).

[image]

I want to suffix value with a % symbol when I start entering input.

1. Initially, it should be "Percentage (%)". Check #3 "AU Small Finance Bank"
2. If the non-zero input value is provided then it should be "{{value}}%". Check #1 "ABB India Ltd"
3. If the input value is not provided or if it is 0 then make it back to "Percentage (%)". I want #2 "ACC Ltd" to show "Percentage (%)", because it was touched but no value was provided.

Link to codepen https://codepen.io/agrawalo/pen/NWKaWMm

```
<input placeholder="Percentage (%)"  id="input_{{stock.code}}" class="stock"/>
```

JS code:

```
$('.stock').on('focus click', function() {
  $(this)[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  $(this).val('%');
})
```

Comment: check out this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form I will help u

Comment: Its called a suffix. Try this solution and see if it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796934/add-a-text-suffix-to-input-type-number?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You could also try something like this: https://codepen.io/swhdesigns/pen/bNwVgG

Comment: Can someone update my codepen ?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal you want the percent inside the box ? because you cant always insert the % along with the data and manipulate it ?

Answer (score -1):

Try value instead of Placeholder

```
<input value="0%"  id="input_{{stock.code}}"/>
```