# Automatically add prefix to textbox input HTML?

Tags: html, input, textbox

I usualy don't work with HTML, however I have a input textbox where a number can be enterd but I need the value to be in milimeters. Is it possible to have a textbox input field where the user can type in a value and the textbox will always show whatever number is typed in the textbox and mm apears after the number even as it is typed...

So as example the user enters the textbox types in 1000 and when they leave that textbox the text changes automatically from 1000 to 1000mm?

Comment: this might help -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796934/add-a-text-suffix-to-input-type-number/49797347

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a text suffix to <input type="number">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796934/add-a-text-suffix-to-input-type-number)