# is it possible screen reader read suffix of input?

Tags: javascript, input, nvda, suffix

I have issue with input type text suffix. F.e. `<input type="text" value="100" />` and suffix "grams".

The expected result:
NVDA read - 100 grams

Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but we really need to see a text-based [mcve] to be sure.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, sorry, I edited

Comment: Please may you read this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/forms/Basic_form_hints

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796934/add-a-text-suffix-to-input-type-number.  However, the accepted answer does not read correctly with a screen reader even though CSS `content` attribute is supposed to be honored when generating screen reader text.  I haven't investigated why the suffix is not being read.